Si as a reflexive pronoun
Ive read through several grammar books now (most of them at least) and nowhere did I see mention of the use of "Si" (with an accent) as a reflexive pronoun.
for example:
Se golpeó a sí mismo
He hit himself.
I had to look it up, and sure enough, "sí" can be used this way, and asking some of my spanish-speaking friends, its actually common, at least in many parts of Mexico.
Can anyone think of a spanish book where this is mentioned?
[update]
Just found it in the one grammar book that I have not read through much of yet.  Its "Rutledge Reference Grammars, a new reference grammar of modern Spanish".

It's common across all varieties of Spanish and is not limited to any one variety. It's in the RAE: https://dle.rae.es/sí

Sí, si se golpea a sí mismo, sí que es reflexivo, si bien de por sí irreflexivo, por no decir absurdo ¿sí?

Para probar la existencia del uso, basta con consultar en un diccionario cualquiera, por ejemplo en el DLE. Están las dos etimologías bien marcadas y diferenciadas: la afirmación viene de sic est y el pronombre reflexivo viene de sibi; las cuales se unificaron en una sola palabra, digamos que por casualidad del destino. Por lo que sí, ese nuevo uso que descubriste es completamente estándar.
Ahora bien, sobre aprender acerca del uso, leería el capítulo ‘Los pronombres reflexivos’ de El buen uso del español, manual de gramática publicado por la RAE y ASALE. Cito algunas partes del capítulo:

Solo son necesariamente reﬂexivos los pronombres sí y
consigo. Todos los demás, excepto yo y tú, que son formas
propias del sujeto, pueden actuar como tales en
determinados contextos.


Los reﬂexivos concuerdan con sus antecedentes en
persona, número y género.


Los pronombres de 3.ª persona él, ella, ello, ellos, ellas
pueden adquirir valor reﬂexivo en contextos en los que
son sustituibles por sí (‘siempre habla de él’ o ‘siempre habla de sí’, ambas correctas)


En las construcciones reﬂexivas con duplicación, la
presencia de mismo es necesaria, ya que su supresión da
lugar a construcciones agramaticales (‘Solo se perjudica a sí mismo’, obligatorio agregar ‘mismo’)

And so on.
Otra variante para los pobres es googlear ‘sí as a reflexive pronoun spanish’, o buscar preguntas similares en el foro.
